RealSense, No device connected
Required Info
Camera Model    Intel RealSense SR305
Firmware Version    v2.50.0
Operating System & Version  Windows 11
Platform    PC
SDK Version v2.50.0
Language    opencv/python
Segment YOLOv10
I will detect objects with YOLOv10, but Realsense does not connect to the depth sensor.
Error starting RealSense pipeline: No device connected
import cv2
import torch
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Configure depth and color streams
pipeline = rs.pipeline()
config = rs.config()
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.depth, 640, 480, rs.format.z16, 30)
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 640, 480, rs.format.bgr8, 30)

# Load YOLO model
model = YOLO(yolov10x.pt)

try:
    # Start streaming and catch potential errors
    try:
        print("Starting RealSense pipeline...")
        pipeline.start(config)
        print("RealSense pipeline started successfully.")
    except RuntimeError as e:
        print(f"Error starting RealSense pipeline: {e}")
        pipeline = None

    if pipeline:
        while True:
            # Wait for a coherent pair of frames: depth and color
            frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
            color_frame = frames.get_color_frame()
            if not color_frame:
                continue

            # Convert images to numpy arrays
            color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())

            # Perform object detection
            results = model(color_image)

            # Display results
            for result in results:
                boxes = result.boxes
                for box in boxes:
                    x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, box.xyxy[0])
                    conf = box.conf[0]
                    cls = int(box.cls[0])
                    label = f'{model.names[cls]} {conf:.2f}'
                    cv2.rectangle(color_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 2)
                    cv2.putText(color_image, label, (x1, y1 - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (255, 0, 0), 2)

            # Show the image
            cv2.imshow('RealSense', color_image)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
finally:
    # Stop streaming if the pipeline was started
    if pipeline:
        print("Stopping RealSense pipeline...")
        pipeline.stop()
        print("RealSense pipeline stopped.")
    # Check if destroyAllWindows exists before calling it
    if hasattr(cv2, 'destroyAllWindows'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

